# Cannot get rid of svn merge conflicts

Tags: svn, merge

We have a branch of our main project which we keep merging into the trunk.

Different developers are cherry-picking their own developments to merge separately, so that they can correspond to a particular JIRA issue.

Every now and then we use the following command in the trunk root directory to find out what hasn't been merged yet:

```
svn merge --dry-run svn://svnhost/repo/app/branch
```

Usually if everything has been merged, it shows no output.

However, this is now giving us a message to say "resolve all conflicts a rerun merge to apply the remaining unmerged revisions".

I have tried merging everything that shows as a conflict, and resolving those conflicts, but they keep coming up, but with different revision numbers.

Here's the full output of the above command (with directories and files renamed):

```
--- Merging r43608 through r43615 into 'directory1':
   C directory1/file1
C    directory1/file2
C    directory1/file3
--- Merging r43609 through r43615 into 'directory2':
   C directory2/file1
C    directory2/file2
C    directory2/file3
--- Merging r43605 through r43615 into 'directory3':
C    directory3/file1
C    directory3/file2
   C directory3/file3
   C directory3/file4
   C directory3/file5
   C directory3/file6
--- Merging r43603 through r43615 into 'directory4':
C    directory4/file1
C    directory4/file2
   C directory4/file3
--- Merging r43603 through r43615 into 'directory5':
C    directory5/file1
C    directory5/file2
C    directory5/file3
   C directory5/file4
U    directory5/file5
C    directory5/file6
   C directory5/file7
   C directory5/file8
   C directory5/file9
C    directory5/file10
   C directory5/file11
 G   directory5
--- Merging r43603 through r43615 into 'directory6':
U    directory6/file1
C    directory6/file2
   C directory6/file3
   C directory6/file4
C    directory6/file5
--- Merging r43517 through r43615 into 'directory7':
   C directory7/file1
   C directory7/file2
   A directory7/file3
   C directory7/file4
   A directory7/file5
--- Merging r43607 through r43615 into 'directory8/file1':
 G   directory8/file1
--- Merging r43534 through r43615 into 'directory9':
C    directory9/file1
   C directory9/file2
   C directory9/file3
   C directory9/file4
   C directory9/file5
   C directory9/file6
   C directory9/file7
   C directory9/file8
   C directory9/file9
   C directory9/file10
   A directory9/file11
   C directory9/file12
   C directory9/file13
   A directory9/file14
   C directory9/file15
   C directory9/file16
C    directory9/file17
   C directory9/file18
   C directory9/file19
U    directory9/file20
   C directory9/file21
C    directory9/file22
   C directory9/file23
C    directory9/file24
C    directory9/file25
   C directory9/file26
   C directory9/file27
   C directory9/file28
   C directory9/file29
   C directory9/file30
C    directory9/file31
C    directory9/file32
 G   directory9
--- Merging r43517 through r43615 into 'directory10/f':
C    directory10/f/file1
--- Merging r43517 through r43615 into 'directory10/l':
U    directory10/l/file1
Summary of conflicts:
  Text conflicts: 23
  Tree conflicts: 39
svn: E155015: One or more conflicts were produced while merging r41855:43503 into
'/clean_trunk' --
resolve all conflicts and rerun the merge to apply the remaining
unmerged revisions
```

Can someone tell me what this output is trying to tell us?

Many of the directories/files listed in this output have already been merged, along with the svn merge-info properties, so I don't know why it's saying that they haven't been merged.

If I perform the merge dry run using the revision range it mentions at the end, then I get nothing:

```
svn merge -r41855:43503 --dry-run svn://svnhost/repo/uniworks/tags/uniworks-2.2.6/
```

Do we need to apply all the merge conflicts and resolve them all in one commit?

I'm pulling my hair out here!

Comment: Have you checked [Resolving SVN merge postponed conflicts recursively](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/328730/resolving-svn-merge-postponed-conflicts-recursively?rq=1). Let me know whether any of mentioned solution works for you.

Comment: Hmmm, that question is over 10 years old, and it doesn't seem to fit our situation. Sorry.

Comment: I know that's very old answer, just wanted to check in case it helps. Check [SVN Book](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/), here you should get something helpful. If you find an answer you can put it here. PS: Ref. taken from [another Old answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8203949/how-to-rebase-branch-without-any-real-commits-in-subversion-limited-access) ;)

Answer (score -1):

SVN when there is conflict, creates temporary files as back-up with revision names, like filename**r123**.txt and filename**r345**.txt

Once you manually merge(resolve) the conflicts, you need to tell SVN, to remove those files by command:

`svn resolved`

> Can someone tell me what this output is trying to tell us?

*'C' stands for conflict, 'U' is for update.*

> Do we need to apply all the merge conflicts and resolve them all in
>   one commit?

*Yes, You need to merge them all in one check-in. Else there could be errors such as definition not found, variables undefined etc. in your build.*

Comment: Sorry , but your answer is not sufficient. We use NetBeans to do the merge/resolve, so the `svn resolved` is not necessary. I already know that 'C' stands for Conflict and 'U' stands for 'Update', but there are 4 columns of letters at the start of each line. What do they all mean? Also, what is the 'Unmerged revisions' at the end telling us? And when I asked about needing to merge them all in one commit, I meant do I need to do that to *resolve the conflicts*, not make a build that works.